# Equality and Quantifiers

Tags: symbolic, logic

I am new to *Mathematica* and to Math. I do not study math in English, so please bear with me as I try to state my questions..

This is what I am trying to "solve":

$$∃!x : A(x) ⇔ ∃x : ¬A(x)$$

In words: "Is 'there is exactly one x for which the assertion A is true' equivalent to 'there is at least one x for which assertion A is not true' ?"

Referred to that I have questions:

- Is this something you would normally do with *Mathematica*?
- In the program I opened a "New Notebook" and typed in:

  ```
  Equivalent[!Exists[x, a[x]], Exists[x, !a[x] ]]
  ```

  and it - surprise! ;) - did not work. What have I done wrong ?
- How would the answer look like ?

Comment: As far as I remember math quantifiers, "there i exactly one x..." is not one of them. They are either "For all x..." or "There is at least one x...". What You are looking for is a uniqueness quantification, but there's no such built-in function in _Mathematica_. Besides, negation of Exists[ ] results in ForAll[ ].

Comment: @WojciechSitkiewicz I guess it could be written as `Exists[x, a[x]] && ForAll[{x,y}, a[x] && a[y] , x==y]` or so

Answer (score 3):

Actually, `∃!` is a standard for "there exists a unique ..." . However, the proposition is false. Consider `A(x)` where `x` is greater than 5. There exists lots of `x` for which `x<=5`. And surely there is not a unique `x`, for `x>5`.

To express `∃!` in Mathematica one needs

```
Exists[x, A[x]] && ForAll[{a, b}, A[a] && A[b] \[Implies] a == b]
```

Then Mathematica can resolve

```
In[98]:= Equivalent[
  Exists[x, A[x]] && ForAll[{a, b}, A[a] && A[b] \[Implies] a == b], 
  Exists[x, Not[A[x]]]] // TautologyQ

Out[98]= False
```

After doing this, I see that the full answer has already been provided.

Answer (score 3):

Based on ssch suggestion I have come up with a following code:

```
Equivalent[Exists[x, a[x]] && ForAll[{x, y}, a[x] && a[y], x == y], 
Exists[x, ! a[x]]] // TautologyQ
```

> False